# AngularFire2 Firebase.update failed snapshot.exists()

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I have been creating an Angular2 application, I want to update profiles of users in Firebase, I'm using AngularFire2.
For example when I'm trying to update user profile who has a key "nmH5ZmawpQgogoCRVFVfNaBN6xg1",when I click in button to update it an error appears
`EXCEPTION: Error in ./ProfilComponent class ProfilComponent - inline template:82:10 caused by: Firebase.update failed: First argument contains a function in property 'users.nmH5ZmawpQgogoCRVFVfNaBN6xg1.$exists' with contents: function () {
        return snapshot.exists();
    }`

user.service.ts

```
  users:FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  updateUser(user:IUser){
   this.users=this.af.database.list('/users');
   this.users.update(user.uid,user);
  }
```

user.ts

```
export interface IUser { 
avatarUrl:string;
 createdDate:string; 
birthDate:string;
 displayName:string; 
email:string; 
gendre:string; 
interests:Interest[];
 job:Job[]; 
location:ILocation; 
plateform:string; 
uid:string;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the solution is to remove $key property and  $exists function from user object:  delete this.user['$key']; delete this.user['$exists'];

Answer (score 1):

In AngularFire2, list items and objects have a `$key` property and an `$exists` function added. See the [`unwrapMapFn`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/2.0.0-beta.8/src/utils.ts#L46-L71) utility function.

As of version [`2.0.0-beta.8`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta8-2017-02-16), the `$key` and `$exists` properties should be non-enumerable and should be ignored by the `update` implementation.

If you don't want to update your AngularFire2 dependency to the latest beta, you can use the following work around:

```ts
updateUser(user: IUser) {
  const { $exists, $key, ...userWithout$ } = user as any;
  this.users = this.af.database.list('/users');
  this.users.update(user.uid, userWithout$);
}
```

However, there have been several bug fixes in recent releases, so updating is encouraged.

Comment: this is my interface IUser,                                                                     export interface IUser {
  avatarUrl:string;
  createdDate:string;
  birthDate:string;
  displayName:string;
  email:string;
  gendre:string;
  interests:Interest[];
  job:Job[];
  location:ILocation;
  plateform:string;
  uid:string;}

Comment: That doesn't change the answer. The list item or object that you receive from AngularFire2 (and, no doubt, cast to the interface) already has the $-prefixed properties. Your interface is just some static typing; the properties will still be part of the instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer to my question, but my interface IUser has no properties $key,$exists,userWithout$ ,I have added those properties to my interface, But it changes nothing

Comment: I see what you are saying re: the interface now. The workaround can be used without adding `$key` and `$exists` to your interface if `as any` is used. However, you should really update to the latest AngularFire2. And you definitely don't need `userWithout$` in your interface - that's just the variable that collects properties other than `$key` and `$exists`.

Answer (score 0):

In short: the object you put in the second argument of the update, may not contain the properties $key and $exists:

```
const key = user.uid;
let userWithout$ = user;
delete userWithout$.$key;
delete userWithout$.$exists;

this.users.update(key, userWithout$);
```

By the way: extra question:

the destructuring line @cartant uses:

```
const { $exists, $key, ...userWithout$ } = user as any;
```

is very nice but didn't work in my case and resulting in the following error: *Property destructuring pattern expected.*

This is ES6 syntax and should be working.
I'm using typescript 2.4.1.
Is something wrong with my tsconfig.json perhaps? (ts compile target for my project must be es5).